# What does ([^:"]+) do in a Ruby regular expression?

Tags: ruby, regex

I can't find a good reference for the apparently special uses of the `^`, `:`, and `"` characters.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It matches a block of characters that are not `:` or `"`.

- `[...]` - Character classes - match characters in this class. For example, `[abc]`, would match one character, `a` or `b` or `c`.
- `[^...]` - Negated Character class.
- `+` - match one or more

See also: [Character Classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

Comment: It also puts it in a capture group.

Answer (score 5):

The syntax `[…]` is a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) that matches one of the character as described inside. With `[^…]` the character class is inverted to that it matches any character except the ones as described inside.

So `[^:"]` describes any arbitrary character except `:` and `"`. And `([^:"]+)` is a group that matches one or more arbitrary characters except `:` and `"`.

Comment: Congratulations on a very well deserved 100K :)

Comment: @codaddict: Thanks. The first 100k are always the hardest. :)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you take a look at http://rubular.com/. Rubular is a Ruby-based regular expression editor. And you can test/write your regular expressions online!

Answer (score 1):

Inside `[]` the only special character is `^`. All other characters have no special meaning when they appear between `[` and `]`.

Comment: `-` and `[:digit:]` named classes have special meaning between `[` and `]`, and `\d` character classes retain their special meaning too.